# Node + Mongodb. $pull not working?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using Node.js and MongoDB and I'm trying to setup a DELETE route. In the function responsible for handling the delete I am using Mongo's "$pull" operator. I've looked at a couple of examples now and I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Here's a sample of how the database documents are setup

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "123abc"
},
"sleepData": [
    {
        "date": "03/28/2016",
        "hour": "11",
        "minute": "11",
        "meridiem": "PM",
        "feeling": "7"
    },
    {
        "date": "03/29/2016",
        "hour": "3",
        "minute": "41",
        "meridiem": "PM",
        "feeling": "1"
    },
    {
        "date": "03/30/2016",
        "hour": "1",
        "minute": "29",
        "meridiem": "AM",
        "feeling": "5"
    },
    {
        "date": "03/30/2016",
        "hour": "1",
        "minute": "38",
        "meridiem": "AM",
        "feeling": "4"
    },
  ]
}
```

*Note the near-duplicate data, thus the reason why my $pull query is so specific.

Here is my function for the route

```
module.exports.DELETE = function(req, res) {
var sleepDataToDelete = {
    date: req.query.date,
    hour: req.query.hour,
    minute: req.query.minute,
    meridiem: req.query.meridiem,
    feeling: req.query.feeling
};

// next code block is what this console prints out
console.log("Deleting req.query:\n", sleepDataToDelete);

var sleepObjectId = req.query.sleepObjectId;
var sleepDataCollection = db.get().collection('sleepData');
sleepDataCollection.update(
    {
        _id: sleepObjectId
    },
    {
        $pull: {
            sleepData: {
                date: sleepDataToDelete.date,
                hour: sleepDataToDelete.hour,
                minute: sleepDataToDelete.minute,
                meridiem: sleepDataToDelete.meridiem,
                feeling: sleepDataToDelete.feeling
            }
        }
    },
    function(err, result) {
        if(err) {
            console.log("err", err);
            return res.status(400).end();
        } else {
            console.log("Count: ", result.result.n);
            console.log("Deleted! :) ");
            return res.status(200).end();
        }
    }
);
```

};

This is what the console.log("Deleting req.query:\n", sleepDataToDelete); prints out, which also matches the third index in the sleepData array.

```
Deleting req.query:
{ 
  date: '03/30/2016',
  hour: '1',
  minute: '29',
  meridiem: 'AM',
  feeling: '5'
}
```

I have even tried putting the json field names in double/single quotes, but that didn't work either. The number of objects modified is 0. I have also tried reducing the "$pull {...}" query to just "date" instead of having "date", "hour", "minute", "meridiem", and "feeling." This still results in 0 modified items from the print statement.

Comment: Something in your actual arguments to `$pull` is not actually matching the content. Note that you do not need **all** the properties, but just the ones necessary to identify the array element to remove i.e `{ "date": "03/29/2016", "hour": "11" }` if there are no other elements with `"hour": "11`. `$pull` is like `$elemMatch` in that the arguments contained are a "query". Also check the `sleepObjecId` is actually an `ObjectId`, as if `nMatched` is actually `0` then you are basically not matching the document.

Comment: @BlakesSeven the reason I am trying to match all the fields is because there could be other objects that only differ by minutes, or maybe hours. I went ahead and checked the sleepObjectId and it is the correct one. What really confuses me is that in order for me to call my delete function, i first run a search function based on a date. if the search function returns data then at that point I am allowed to delete a specific object in the array.

Comment: What you should have taken away from the comment is "check your values". If you still cannot work it out based on that, then you **need** to include the values of the variables in use within your question. All we see are the variable names themselves. It is the "content" that is the problem.

Comment: Ahh, okay okay, let me edit my post then.

Comment: I told you the `_id` is a "string". Change this `var sleepObjectId = new mongodb.ObjectId(req.query.sleepObjectId);`. And next time `console.log(result)` where you will see the obvious `nMatched` as `0` because you never matched the document.

Comment: @BlakesSeven, I honestly don't know how I missed that. All my other functions have the 'new ObjectId()' code. Wow. sorry to waste your time. And low and behold, that was the issue...... *sigh*

Answer (score 0):

As @BlakesSeven pointed out, I was not passing in an ObjectId in my query. So, credit goes to him. Needless to say, this solved my issue.